# Formating number string with commas for currency type dispaly

Tags: python

Is there an easy way in python to format a number with commas ie 11222.33 would print as: $11,222.33.

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
def formatMoney(number):
    res = str(number)

    # Number of digits before decimal
    n = res.find('.')
    n = n if (n >= 0) else len(res)
    if n < 4:
        return res[:n+3]

    # Location of first comma
    start = n % 3
    start = start if (start > 0) else 3

    # Break into parts
    parts = [res[:start]]
    parts += [res[i:i+3] for i in range(start, n - 3, 3)]
    # Last part includes 3 digits before decimal and 2 after
    parts += [res[n-3:n+3]]

    return ",".join(parts)
```

But I feel like I must be reinventing the wheel here. Have I missed a package in the standard library, or a more obvious way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> a = 11222.33
>>> "${:,.2f}".format(a)
'$11,222.33'
>>> a = 111111111222.33
>>> "${:,.2f}".format(a)
'$111,111,111,222.33'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
print(locale.currency(11222.33, grouping=True))
```

yields

```
$11,222.33
```

`en_US.UTF-8` is just an example, of course.

On Unix, you can run

```
% locale -a
```

to see what locales are available on your machine. I don't know what the Windows equivalent is, unfortunately.

---

```
import subprocess
import locale
proc = subprocess.Popen(['locale', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
for name in out.splitlines():
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, name)
    try:
        currency = locale.currency(11222.33, grouping=True)
        print('{}: {}'.format(name, currency))
    except ValueError: pass
```

yields (depending on the locales installed on your machine, something like):

```
el_CY.utf8: 11.222,33€
el_GR.utf8: 11.222,33€
en_AG: $11,222.33
en_AG.utf8: $11,222.33
en_AU.utf8: $11,222.33
en_BW.utf8: Pu11,222.33
en_CA.utf8: $11,222.33
en_DK.utf8: kr 11.222,33
en_GB.utf8: £11,222.33
en_HK.utf8: HK$11,222.33
en_IE.utf8: €11,222.33
en_IN: ₹ 11,222.33
en_IN.utf8: ₹ 11,222.33
en_NG: ₦11,222.33
en_NG.utf8: ₦11,222.33
en_NZ.utf8: $11,222.33
en_PH.utf8: Php11,222.33
en_SG.utf8: $11,222.33
en_US.utf8: $11,222.33
en_ZA.utf8: R11,222.33
en_ZM: K11,222.33
en_ZM.utf8: K11,222.33
en_ZW.utf8: Z$11,222.33
tr_TR.utf8: 11.222,33 YTL
```